# Swift compiler error using dictionary lookup and cast in optional binding

Tags: macos, swift

I'm doing a dictionary lookup from the `infoDictionary` property of the main `NSBundle`. This works properly:

```
let infoDict = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary
var item = infoDict["CFBundleExecutable"]
if let stringValue = item as? String {
   ...
}
```

But, I'd like to chain it all together. However, when I do, I receive a compiler error:

```
if let stringValue = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary["CFBundleExecutable"] as? String {
    ...
}
```

The error is:

`'String' is not a subtype of '(NSObject, AnyObject)'`

I realize this is one of those cryptic Swift compiler messages that means something much more trivial than what it explicitly states - but I can't determine how my two above code snippets differ - why one works, and one does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` is not an object; use `NSString` instead:

```
if let stringValue = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary["CFBundleExecutable"] as? NSString {
    ...
}
```

If you want `stringValue` to be a `String` instead of an `NSString`:

```
if let stringValue:String = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary["CFBundleExecutable"] as? NSString {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, sure enough. I keep forgetting `String` is a struct. Thanks!